# How do I unfreeze my Gui while running a bot?

Tags: python, selenium, pyqt5

I have a rarely big problem with my code. Currently I'm building a Whatsapp Bot  with an interface. Now when I start running the Bot I can't stop it at all. I googled a  lot and know I need a thread, but all I tried went wrong. Please help me with this!! All that is blocked out can be ignored and are just some fails from trying to solve this problem.
Here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys, threading, time

class interface(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initMe()


    def initMe(self):
        self.boldFont = QtGui.QFont()
        self.boldFont.setBold(True)
        self.setGeometry(1200, 250, 600, 500)
        self.title = self.setWindowTitle("Whatsapp Bot interface")
        self.Layout_components()
        self.labels()
        self.input()
        self.button()
        self.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15))
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Bot.png"))

        self.show()


    def Layout_components(self):
        self.exit_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Exit", self)
        self.stop_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Stop", self)
        self.start_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Start", self)
        self.exit_.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.stop_.triggered.connect(self.stop)
        self.start_.triggered.connect(self.start)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file = menubar.addMenu("Bot")
        file.addAction(self.exit_)
        file.addAction(self.stop_)
        file.addAction(self.start_)

    def labels(self):

        labelp1 = QLabel("picture", self)
        labelp1.setPixmap(QPixmap("Bot.png"))
        labelp1.setGeometry(340, 100, 210, 180)

        labelp2 = QLabel("picture1", self)
        labelp2.setPixmap(QPixmap("whatsapp_symbol.png"))
        labelp2.setScaledContents(True)
        labelp2.resize(80, 80)
        labelp2.setGeometry(50, 400, 80, 80)

        label1 = QLabel("description", self)
        label1.setGeometry(50, 40, 500, 50)
        label1.setText("Welcome to my Whatsappbot. Are you ready to fuck other people with endless spam up. Have fun!!!")
        label1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14))
        label1.setStyleSheet("border : 2px solid black;")
        label1.setWordWrap(True)

        label2 = QLabel("adress", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 100, 150, 50)
        label2.setText("adressed to: ")

        label2 = QLabel("message", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 300, 150, 50)
        label2.setText("message: ")

        label2 = QLabel("amount", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 200, 200, 50)
        label2.setText("amount of messages: ")

        self.label_input = QLabel("counter", self)
        self.label_input.setGeometry(170, 260, 80, 20)
        self.label_input.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15))
        self.label_input.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_input.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid black")


    def input(self):
        self.input_adressed = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_adressed.setGeometry(50, 150, 150, 30)
        self.input_adressed.textChanged.connect(self.clicked_adressed)

        self.input_message = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_message.setGeometry(50, 350, 150, 30)
        self.input_message.textChanged.connect(self.clicked_message)

        self.input_amount = QSlider(self)
        self.input_amount.setGeometry(50, 240, 100, 70)
        self.input_amount.setMaximum(1000)
        self.input_amount.valueChanged.connect(self.clicked_amount)

    def button(self):

        self.but_stop = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.but_stop.setGeometry(340, 360, 210, 50)
        self.but_stop.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop)

        self.but_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.but_start.setGeometry(340, 300, 210, 50)
        self.but_start.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_start.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.but_exit = QPushButton("Exit", self)
        self.but_exit.setGeometry(340, 420, 210, 50)
        self.but_exit.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    def clicked_amount(self):

        self.amount = self.input_amount.value()
        if self.amount >= 0:
            self.label_input.setText(f"{self.amount}")

        return self.amount

    def clicked_adressed(self):

        #print(self.input_adressed.text())
        return self.input_adressed.text()

    def clicked_message(self):

        return self.input_message.text()

    def stop(self):
        print("programm stopps ...")


    def exit(self):
        #print("programm exits ...")
        app.exit()
        sys.exit()

    def start(self):
        pop_up = QMessageBox(self)
        pop_up.setWindowTitle("Start Bot")
        pop_up.setText("Do you really wanna start the spam ?!")
        pop_up.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        pop_up.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Yes)
        pop_up.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Yes)
        x = pop_up.exec_()

        if x == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("programm starts ...")
            #self.worker_start()
            self.main()

    # def worker_start(self):
    #         self.worker = WorkerThread()
    #         self.worker.start()
    #         self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker_finished)
    #         self.worker.update_progress.connect(self.update_progress)
    #
    # def worker_finished(self):
    #     QMessageBox.information(self, "Done", "Worker thread complete")


    def main(self):

        message = self.clicked_message()
        addressed = self.clicked_adressed()
        profile_path = "user-data-dir=/home/daniel/.config/google-chrome/storing"

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(profile_path)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=options)
        browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

        time.sleep(4)
        search = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#side > div.SgIJV > div > label > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text")))
        search.send_keys(addressed)
        time.sleep(1)
        search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        send = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#main > footer > div.vR1LG._3wXwX.copyable-area > div._2A8P4._2A1WX > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text")))

        for i in range(self.clicked_amount()):
            send.send_keys(message)
            send.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# class WorkerThread(QThread, interface):
#     update_progress = pyqtSignal(int)
#     def run(self):
#         for x in range(100):
#             print(x)
#             time.sleep(2)
#             self.update_progress.emit(x)

            # self.setEnabled(True)
            # message = self.clicked_message()
            # addressed = self.clicked_adressed()
            # profile_path = "user-data-dir=/home/daniel/.config/google-chrome/storing"
            #
            # options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            # options.add_argument(profile_path)
            # browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=options)
            # browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
            #
            # time.sleep(4)
            # search = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
            #     (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#side > div.SgIJV > div > label > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text")))
            # search.send_keys(addressed)
            # time.sleep(1)
            # search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            # send = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            #                                                                                           "#main > footer > div.vR1LG._3wXwX.copyable-area > div._2A8P4._2A1WX > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text")))
            #
            # for i in range(self.clicked_amount()):
            #     send.send_keys(message)
            #     send.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
x = interface()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in this case is to get the information from the GUI (amount, adressed and message) and execute the time-consuming function in another thread passing the information to it.

```py
from functools import cached_property
import sys
import threading
import time


from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Worker:
    def start(self, amount, adressed, message):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute,
            args=(
                amount,
                adressed,
                message,
            ),
            daemon=True,
        ).start()

    def _execute(self, amount, adressed, message):
        profile_path = "user-data-dir=/home/daniel/.config/google-chrome/storing"

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(profile_path)
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=options)
        browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

        time.sleep(4)
        search = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "#side > div.SgIJV > div > label > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text",
                )
            )
        )
        search.send_keys(addressed)
        time.sleep(1)
        search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        send = WebDriverWait(browser, 500).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
                (
                    By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                    "#main > footer > div.vR1LG._3wXwX.copyable-area > div._2A8P4._2A1WX > div > div._2_1wd.copyable-text.selectable-text",
                )
            )
        )

        for i in range(amount):
            send.send_keys(message)
            send.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


class interface(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initMe()

    def initMe(self):
        self.boldFont = QFont()
        self.boldFont.setBold(True)
        self.setGeometry(1200, 250, 600, 500)
        self.title = self.setWindowTitle("Whatsapp Bot interface")
        self.Layout_components()
        self.labels()
        self.input()
        self.button()
        self.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15))
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Bot.png"))

        self.show()

    def Layout_components(self):
        self.exit_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Exit", self)
        self.stop_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Stop", self)
        self.start_ = QAction(QIcon("Bot.png"), "Start", self)
        self.exit_.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.stop_.triggered.connect(self.stop)
        self.start_.triggered.connect(self.start)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file = menubar.addMenu("Bot")
        file.addAction(self.exit_)
        file.addAction(self.stop_)
        file.addAction(self.start_)

    def labels(self):

        labelp1 = QLabel("picture", self)
        labelp1.setPixmap(QPixmap("Bot.png"))
        labelp1.setGeometry(340, 100, 210, 180)

        labelp2 = QLabel("picture1", self)
        labelp2.setPixmap(QPixmap("whatsapp_symbol.png"))
        labelp2.setScaledContents(True)
        labelp2.resize(80, 80)
        labelp2.setGeometry(50, 400, 80, 80)

        label1 = QLabel("description", self)
        label1.setGeometry(50, 40, 500, 50)
        label1.setText(
            "Welcome to my Whatsappbot. Are you ready to fuck other people with endless spam up. Have fun!!!"
        )
        label1.setFont(QFont("Arial", 14))
        label1.setStyleSheet("border : 2px solid black;")
        label1.setWordWrap(True)

        label2 = QLabel("adress", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 100, 150, 50)
        label2.setText("adressed to: ")

        label2 = QLabel("message", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 300, 150, 50)
        label2.setText("message: ")

        label2 = QLabel("amount", self)
        label2.setGeometry(50, 200, 200, 50)
        label2.setText("amount of messages: ")

        self.label_input = QLabel("counter", self)
        self.label_input.setGeometry(170, 260, 80, 20)
        self.label_input.setFont(QFont("Arial", 15))
        self.label_input.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_input.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid black")

    def input(self):
        self.input_adressed = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_adressed.setGeometry(50, 150, 150, 30)

        self.input_message = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input_message.setGeometry(50, 350, 150, 30)

        self.input_amount = QSlider(self)
        self.input_amount.setGeometry(50, 240, 100, 70)
        self.input_amount.setMaximum(1000)

        self.input_amount.valueChanged.connect(self.label_input.setNum)

    def button(self):
        self.but_stop = QPushButton("Stop", self)
        self.but_stop.setGeometry(340, 360, 210, 50)
        self.but_stop.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop)

        self.but_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.but_start.setGeometry(340, 300, 210, 50)
        self.but_start.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_start.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.but_exit = QPushButton("Exit", self)
        self.but_exit.setGeometry(340, 420, 210, 50)
        self.but_exit.setFont(self.boldFont)
        self.but_exit.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    @cached_property
    def worker(self):
        return Worker()

    @property
    def amount(self):
        value = self.input_amount.value()
        return value

    @property
    def adressed(self):
        return self.input_adressed.text()

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self.input_message.text()

    def stop(self):
        print("programm stopps ...")

    def exit(self):
        # print("programm exits ...")
        QCoreApplication.quit()

    def start(self):
        pop_up = QMessageBox(self)
        pop_up.setWindowTitle("Start Bot")
        pop_up.setText("Do you really wanna start the spam ?!")
        pop_up.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        pop_up.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Yes)
        pop_up.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Yes)
        if pop_up.exec_() == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print("programm starts ...")
            self.worker.start(self.amount, self.adressed, self.message)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
x = interface()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```